# React native maps Android Callout not streching according to the content

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

So, I have implemented `react-native-maps` into my app and added a marker. I am using the `callout` to show some info about that position, such as some counters and some times. The problem I have encountered it's when I am using the `ref.current.showCallout()` to update the content of the `callout`, because I fetch the times from the server, thus there's a slightly delay to the accesibility of the information(some info updates later => more content to show in `callout`). So, on the `iOS` the `callout` looks good, and when I get the `response` from the server, the callout streches (is changing it's `height`) accordingly to the content to show all the times(they are rendered looking like a 'list', every time it's a row actually). But on `Android`, the `height` remains somehow the same. The `android` `callout` seems to have a `standard height`. Below it's the code I am using for the `callout`:

```
<Callout tooltip={true} style={{ flex: 1}}>
  <View>
    <View style={styles.calloutContainer}>
      <View style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Teatru</Text>
        <Text style={{margin:5,fontSize:14}}>{ora}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}
              color={albastru_scope}
              size={18}
              margin= {5}/>
          <Text>{auth.stare.nr_persoane}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWalking}
              color={albastru_scope}
              size={18}
              margin= {5}/>
          <Text>{auth.stare.nr_pietoni}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBicycle}
              color={albastru_scope}
              size={18}
              margin= {5}/>
          <Text>{auth.stare.nr_biciclisti}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCar}
              color={albastru_scope}
              size={18}
              margin= {5}/>
          <Text>{auth.stare.nr_vehicule}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{marginTop:7}}>
        <View style={styles.textTitleStyleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.textTitleStyle}>Următoarele autobuze</Text>
        </View>
        {arrivals=="1"? (<Text>Nimic :(</Text>) : (
          arrivals.map((arrival)=> (
            <Text key={arrival.route_sn}>Linia {arrival.route} : {arrival.arrival}</Text>
          ))
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</Callout>
```

I have tried to add to `callout style` : `{ height: 200}` but nothing happend. Tried to add static `height` to the `callout childrens` too but again, on `Android` nothing happend. Changing those `heights` were shown on `iOS` but not on `android`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue and I will write it down, in case someone else's comes by this problem.

Having the

```
arrivals=="1"? (<Text>Nimic </Text>) : (
          arrivals.map((arrival)=> (
            <Text key={arrival.route_sn}>Linia {arrival.route} : {arrival.arrival}</Text>
          ))
```

to render the components, firstly the `arrivals` will actually be `1`, so the `callout` will render using only 1 row for that part. Thus, when the information updates, the `height` of the `callout` will stay the same, having for the

```
arrivals.map((arrival)=> (
            <Text key={arrival.route_sn}>Linia {arrival.route} : {arrival.arrival}</Text>
          )
```

only 1 row available to render.